# R Graphic Coding: Back to Back Histogram Plot

Tags: r, plot

The task I'm trying to accomplish means creating a plot of back to back histograms, as in this following pictures.

[image: http://imgur.com/EKDwuH8 (I don't have high enough REP to post direct images)]

First things first, YES, this is an assignment supplied by a professor, and I really want to get my head around graphics than just get the code that produces this function, because then I'll still be just as useless, and defy the point of the assignment anyway.

So far, using the layout function, I've created a 7 panel layout, using a 2 by 2 matrix, because when using an odd number matrix, I get an excess centre panel between my plots, which I don't know how to remove, so this is the layout I have:

```
m = rbind(c(0,0),c(7,7),c(5,6),c(4,4),c(1,2),c(3,3),c(0,0))
layout(m,widths = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1),heights = c(1,0.56,0.5,0.5,4,0.5,1))
layout.show(7)
```

And I have individually plotted both the female and male data:

```
Female =
c(85, 71, 52, 56, 19, 1, 4, 4, 62, 3, 50, 87, 58, 92)

Male = 100- Female

Subject =
c("Humanities", "Social Sciences", "Science", "Economics", "Engineering", 
"Construction", "Electrical Engineering", "Vehicles and Transport", 
"Business Studies", "Industrial Engineering", "Agriculture", 
"Nursing (Care)", "Catering", "Nursing")

xlim = c(0,1.06*max(Female,Male))
ylim = c(0,length(Subject))

yt = 1:length(Subject)
yb = yt - 1

plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = rev(xlim), ylim = ylim,
        xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
rect(0, yb, Male, yt, col = "lightgray")
axis(1)
box()

plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim,
        xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
rect(0, yb, Female, yt, col = "lightgray")
axis(1)
box()
```

Now, my main cause for help is in firstly, getting the categorical names to span across the bars, I am unsure how to label the bars themselves, when they are in the plot itself, and then how to establish a legend.

Any pointers in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you posted a link to the correct pic? That doesn't look like back-to-back histograms. And this is discrete data. So it's not even really a histogram. You just want barplots? And I still don't understand this layout, what's supposed to go in boxes 3-7??

Comment: The way I've been taught is to create layout boxes and make them into label panels, for the main title, axis(top and bottom) and there are two labels missing from the picture. 

Sorry, I meant barplots, that was just me being a bit of a tool.